# Update datagridview after delete something

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to refresh my datagridview after delete something from database. The code that I am actually using on my delete button is

```
    Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
            If txtDelete.Text <> "" Then
                If MsgBox("Deseja apagar o ficheiro " & txtDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) Then
                    SQL.DataDelete("DELETE FROM infofile WHERE Filename='" & txtDelete.Text & "' ")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Por favor introduza um ficheiro a apagar!")
            End If
        RefreshDGV()
        End Sub
```

And I've created a Sub method

```
Sub RefreshDGV()
        Dim str1 As String = "SELECT * FROM infofile"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = SQLDataSet.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

This is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM infofile"
Dim dtb As New DataTable
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
cnn.Open()
Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
dad.Fill(dtb)
End Using
cnn.Close()

DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb

End Using
```